# How to instantiate a variable to call a method

Tags: c#-3.0

Is their a way in c# to instantiate a variable into a method call without using a switch statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean like polymorphism?

Comment: Are you asking for eval-like functionality, where you can call a function by its name when it is contained in a string variable?

Comment: -1 for not explaining or giving details.  I hate these types of questions!

Comment: Please give us an example of what you mean with a switch, and we'll tell you if there's an alternative without the switch.

Comment: I sometimes find it quite hard to put stuff into words, as i'm trying to design summat.

Comment: @scope-creep: Giving sample code which indicates what you *want* to be able to do, even if it's invalid, would be useful. The phrase "instantiate a variable into a method call" is pretty meaningless at the moment.

Comment: Hi John, 
I understand, i've been trying to visualize the best way of solving this problem for the last 3 weeks, and it's driving me up the wall, which is how do you assign and append of values from one xml message to another and enable that on the fly based on a user defined query, assign expression.

Comment: @JonH, maybe it's a newbie user, and seems that Bob understood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take a string and use that string to call a method on an object, this can be done with [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15.aspx) without the need for a `switch` statement.

```
string methodName = "ToString";
var method = typeof(TypeYourMethodExistsOn).GetMethod(methodName);
method.Invoke(objectInstance, null);
```

Comment: Aah Bob, 
That was a quick answer, and I think it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Keep in mind that the switch statement is likely faster than using reflection.

Comment: Well, each of the method to call would extract a particular value out of a xml message. According to the schema, there is about 80 odd unique values you can extract, which would make for a big switch statement, but that would still be faster than reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clear, either.  If you don't want to use reflection (heavy sometimes), for dynamically calling methods using a variable, you could use something like a collection containing delegates as values and call them.

I use an extremely like dictionary object to dynamically call a known method based on string inputs.

psuedo code:

```
delegate void Del(int i, double j);

class MathClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MathClass m = new MathClass();

        // Delegate instantiation using "MultiplyNumbers"
        Del d = m.MultiplyNumbers;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("mult", d);

        // Invoke the delegate object.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Invoking the delegate using 'MultiplyNumbers':");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            ((del) ht("mult"))(i, 2);
        }
    }

    // Declare the associated method.
    void MultiplyNumbers(int m, double n)
    {
        System.Console.Write(m * n + " ");
    }
}
```